# Django error invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, django

I'm making a sports forecasting app which should be able to let people keep track of their math forecasts.

The HTML has 48 matches so far and they have to fill the score for each one, however when I try to save scores this error keeps coming up:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Here is my view:

```
@login_required(login_url="/")
def inicio(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Pronosticos(request.POST)
        for i in range(48):
            pronostico, _ = PartidosUsuarios.objects.get_or_create(idUsuario=request.user, idPartido=request.POST.get("idPartido"+str(i), ""), PaisL=request.POST.get("PaisL"+str(i), ""), Local=request.POST.get("Local"+str(i), ""), Visita=request.POST.get("Visita"+str(i), ""), PaisV=request.POST.get("PaisV"+str(i), ""), Capturado="Si")
            if pronostico.Local > pronostico.Visita:
                pronostico.Resultado = "Local"
                pronostico.save()
            elif pronostico.Visita > pronostico.Local:
                pronostico.Resultado = "Visita"
                pronostico.save()
            elif pronostico.Local == pronostico.Visita:
                pronostico.Resultado = "Empate"
                pronostico.save()
        return render(request, "brasil/inicio.html")
    partidos_fifa = PartidosFifa.objects.order_by("Partido")[:64]
    context = {"partidos_fifa": partidos_fifa}
    return render(request, "brasil/inicio.html", context)
```

forms.py

```
class Pronosticos(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PartidosUsuarios
        fields = ["idPartido", "PaisL", "Local", "Visita", "PaisV"]
```

models.py

```
class PartidosUsuarios(models.Model):
    idUsuario = models.OneToOneField(User)
    idPartido = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    PaisL = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Local = models.IntegerField(max_length=11, default=0)
    Visita = models.IntegerField(max_length=11, default=0)
    PaisV = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Resultado = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Puntos = models.IntegerField(max_length=11, default=0)
    Capturado = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="No")
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.idPartido)
```

And lastly an html example for the forms and inputs:

```
<tr>
                    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="idPartido1" id="idPartido"/>
                    <td><input value="Brasil" class="pronosticos" name="PaisL1" id="PaisL"/></td>
                    <td><input name="Local1" id="Local"/></td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td><input name="Visita1" id="Visita"/></td>
                    <td><input value="Croacia"  class="pronosticos" name="PaisV1" id="PaisV"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="idPartido2" id="idPartido"/>
                    <td><input value="México" class="pronosticos" name="PaisL2" id="PaisL"/></td>
                    <td><input name="Local2" id="Local"/></td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td><input name="Visita2" id="Visita"/></td>
                    <td><input value="Camerún"  class="pronosticos" name="PaisV2" id="PaisV"/></td>
                </tr>
```

It seems it's complaining about the line in the view that starts with "pronostico, _ ="

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT
Here is the error traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/inicio/

Django Version: 1.6.2
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'brasil2014',
 'south')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/eduardoalcocer/Desktop/PAGINAS WEB/Quinielas/brasil2014/views.py" in inicio
  84.             pronostico, _ = PartidosUsuarios.objects.get_or_create(idUsuario=request.user, idPartido=request.POST.get("idPartido"+str(i), ""), PaisL=request.POST.get("PaisL"+str(i), ""), Local=request.POST.get("Local"+str(i), ""), Visita=request.POST.get("Visita"+str(i), ""), PaisV=request.POST.get("PaisV"+str(i), ""), Capturado="Si")
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in get_or_create
  154.         return self.get_queryset().get_or_create(**kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get_or_create
  373.             return self.get(**lookup), False
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  298.         clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
  590.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  608.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1198.         clause = self._add_q(where_part, used_aliases)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
  1234.                     current_negated=current_negated)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_filter
  1125.         clause.add(constraint, AND)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/tree.py" in add
  104.         data = self._prepare_data(data)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py" in _prepare_data
  79.             value = obj.prepare(lookup_type, value)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py" in prepare
  352.             return self.field.get_prep_lookup(lookup_type, value)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_lookup
  1079.         return super(IntegerField, self).get_prep_lookup(lookup_type, value)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_lookup
  369.             return self.get_prep_value(value)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  1073.         return int(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /inicio/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: Any trace back of your error?

Comment: Print out `request.POST` before the loop and show us what is it. Something valuable is missing there.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes because are you're trying to store a empty string '' is a integerfield.

Check form values before use them.

Comment: This is obvious. The more interesting thing is why `request.user` is empty despite this view requires to be logged in.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo What makes you think it's `request.user` that's causing the error? More likely to be `idPartido`.

Comment: I don't think so: `idPartido = models.CharField(max_length=20)`

Comment: It's not `idPartido`, it's one of `Local` or `Visita`. If you used your form class you wouldn't have to worry so much about this.